# cannot access to docker container web app by using IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I'm using Linux containers on Windows and containerize a simple web app to test.
Firstly I create a network with:

```
docker network create --subnet 192.168.15.0/24 new_network
```

Afterthat I run

```
docker container run -d --name web1 --publish 8080:8080 --network new_network test:latest
```

I inspect and know that IP of that container is 192.168.15.2. But I cannot access to this via 192.168.15.2 or ip:8080. However, when I'm using localhost:8080, it works!
Could pls show me what is the problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's normal behavior on Docker Desktop for Windows. Please refer to [docker-for-windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/) and [windowscontainers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/building-sample-app)